# Flexible heap space allocation to Hadoop MapReduce Mapper tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to configure my Hadoop cluster (CDH4), running MapReduce1. I'm in a situation where I need to run both mappers that require such a large amount of Java heap space that I couldn't possible run more than 1 mapper per node - but at the same time I want to be able to run jobs that can benefit from many mappers per node.

I'm configuring the cluster through the Cloudera management UI, and the Max Map Tasks and mapred.map.child.java.opts appear to be quite static settings.

What I would like to have is something like a heap space pool with X GB available, that would accommodate both kinds of jobs without having to reconfigure the MapReduce service each time. If I run 1 mapper, it should assign X GB heap - if I run 8 mappers, it should assign X/8 GB heap.

I have considered both the Maximum Virtual Memory and the Cgroup Memory Soft/Hard limits, but neither will get me exactly what I want. Maximum Virtual Memory is not effective, since it still is a per task setting. The Cgroup setting is problematic because it does not seem to actually restrict the individual tasks to a lower amount of heap if there is more of them, but rather will allow the task to use too much memory and then kill the process when it does.

Can the behavior I want to achieve be configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(PS you should use the newer name of this property with Hadoop 2 / CDH4: `mapreduce.map.java.opts`. But both should still be recognized.)

The value you configure in your cluster is merely a default. It can be overridden on a per-job basis. You should leave the default value from CDH, or configure it to something reasonable for normal mappers.

For your high-memory job only, in your client code, set `mapreduce.map.java.opts` in your `Configuration` object for the `Job` before you submit it.

The answer gets more complex if you are running MR2/YARN since it no longer schedules by 'slots' but by container memory. So memory enters the picture in a new, different way with new, different properties. (It confuses me, and I'm even at Cloudera.)

In a way it would be better, because you express your resource requirement in terms of memory, which is good here. You would set `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` as well to a size about 30% larger than your JVM heap size since this is the memory allowed to the whole process. It would be set higher by you for high-memory jobs in the same way. Then Hadoop can decide how many mappers to run, and decide where to put the workers for you, and use as much of the cluster as possible per your configuration. No fussing with your own imaginary resource pool.

In MR1, this is harder to get right. Conceptually you want to set the maximum number of mappers per worker to 1 via `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum`, along with your heap setting, but just for the high-memory job. I don't know if the client can request or set this though on a per-job basis. I doubt it as it wouldn't quite make sense. You can't really approach this by controlling the number of mappers just because you have to hack around to even find out, let alone control, the number of mappers it will run.

I don't think OS-level settings will help. In a way these resemble more how MR2 / YARN thinks about resource scheduling. Your best bet may be to (move to MR2 and) use MR2's resource controls and let it figure the rest out.

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize this could be set at a per-job configuration level. That should do it.

It seems to me that since this is possible it is a good idea to set the Cgroup settings, since any ordinary cluster user might accidentally request a heap size that is too high and start bringing down nodes.

I will also consider moving to MR2.